# Strange mysqli_error behavior in loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a script that I'm working on which parses a CSV file and then puts this into a MySQL DB.  I have everything working as desired except that there is a duplicate primary key in the file I'm developing with, which is fine as this forces me to ensure that the error handling is working as desired.  The problem is that I want the script to throw the duplicate error and continue processing so this means that "or die" is not an option.  I am just simply testing for a "false" query result but this is causing every single insert after the duplicate to repeat the duplicate error spamming hundreds or potentially thousands of duplicate key errors.

Here is the portion of the code in question... (UPDATE: Including basically entire script.)

```
$file = fopen("Temp/03132014all.csv","r");
$out_file = fopen("Temp/clean_ouput.csv",'w');
$cnt_IN = 0; $invalid = 0; $cnt_good = 0;
$inv_yr = "/^0000/";

while(! feof($file)) {
$lead = fgetcsv($file);
if ($lead[1] != "surname") {
    $dt = explode(" ",$lead[9]);
    $time = isset($dt[2]) ? $dt[2] : 0;
    $date = $dt[0];
    if (empty($lead[3]) || empty($lead[8]) || empty($lead[9]) || preg_match($inv_yr,$lead[9])) { // eliminate invalid leads first
        $invalid++;
    } elseif ($lead[6] == "IN") {  // Test for leads from Indiana 
        $cnt_IN++;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO indiana_leads 
                (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Address, City, State, ZIP, Phone, Gender, Lead_Date, Lead_Time, Lead_IP)
                VALUES ('$lead[0]','$lead[1]','$lead[2]','$lead[4]','$lead[5]','$lead[6]','$lead[7]','$lead[8]','$lead[13]',STR_TO_DATE('$date','%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('$time','%H:%i'),'$lead[2]')";

    } else {
        $cnt_good++;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO vb_leads_test
                (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Address, City, State, ZIP, Phone, Gender, Lead_Date, Lead_Time, Lead_IP)
                VALUES ('$lead[0]','$lead[1]','$lead[2]','$lead[4]','$lead[5]','$lead[6]','$lead[7]','$lead[8]','$lead[13]',STR_TO_DATE('$date','%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('$time','%H:%i'),'$lead[2]')";
        $out_array = array($lead[0],$lead[1],$lead[2],$lead[4],$lead[5],$lead[6],$lead[7],$lead[8],$lead[13],$date,$time,$lead[2]);
        fputcsv($out_file, $out_array);
    }
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); // or die(mysqli_error($con));;
if (!$result) {
    $error = mysqli_error($con);
    echo $error;
    //$result = true;
}
} 
}
```

As you can see I attempted to force the $result back to "true" after the error, but I still keep getting the error spammed to the browser/log for every new insert.  I assume that I'm doing something simple wrong here but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? Not show the errors at all? Show the error once? Please clarify.

Comment: Don't you realize that mysqli_error() **doesn't** take part in this?

Comment: BTW, if you want to silently ignore duplicate errors, simply run INSERT IGNORE ... query. This will eliminate all the hundreds duplicate key errors.

Comment: Actually, I would like to know about duplicate primary key issues and have them logged.

Comment: well then - just log them.

Comment: You'd do yourself a HUGE favor if **INDENT** your code, making it READABLE

Answer (score -1):

--Updated

Create a log file to record the duplicate entries instead of printing them to the screen.

at top:

```
$duplicate_key_file = fopen("Temp/duplicate_key.csv",'w');
```

then replace the 'if' at the bottom of the page with this:

```
if (!$result) {
      $duplicate_key_array = array($lead[0],$lead[1],$lead[2],$lead[4],$lead[5],$lead[6],$lead[7],$lead[8],$lead[13],$date,$time,$lead[2]);
      fputcsv($duplicate_key_file , $duplicate_key_array);
}
```

Note: this section came from you own code

Comment: You don't get the question.

Comment: Why did you convert your answer into comment?

Comment: Is there a better way to ask questions about a question?  If so I'd do that instead.

Comment: you should ask in the comments and answer in answers. As simple as that